# something wrong while calling a method

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
student [] s =new student[100];
int index = 0;  

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){   
   System.out.println("Do you want to add new student \n \t if not enter (n) or (N) to exit  ");

   String id=kb.next();

   if(id.equals("n") || id.equals("N")){
       System.exit(0);
   }
   else {
     for(int q = 1; q<4;q++){
         System.out.println("Enter Quiz "+q+" score");
         double score=kb.nextInt();
         s[i].addQuiz(score);
     }
   }
   addStudent(s , i , id );

   }
}

public void addStudent(student[] old, int index , String id){       
    old [index]= new student(id);
}
```

java give me error in add student method call 
and i dont relly no if my array passing is correct or not :(

Comment: How about including a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your variable i goes out of scope from for loop. So add this statement `addStudent(s , i , id );` just before closing for loop.

Also i believe you are calling addStudent from main method which is static and calling non static method, in that case change the method definition as:

```
public static void addStudent(student[] old, int index, String id) {
```

And that should work.

Comment: @zainab.a.k update your code in question post bringing addstudent call in for loop. I found weird thing in your code as well and updated my answer accordingly. Add the error that you are getting.

Comment: 'i' doesn't go out of scope in his for loop, I think you are mixing the 2 for loops.

Comment: else {
       
         for(int q = 1; q<4;q++){
             System.out.println("Enter Quiz "+q+" score");
             double score=kb.nextInt();
             s[i].addQuiz(score);
             
         }
          addStudent(s , i , id );  
       }

Comment: @zainab.a.k please update the question with whatever you have now after changing and please let us know what error your are getting.

Comment: i dont no how to update the question , the error is "non static method addStudent cannot be refrenced from static context"

Comment: @almasshaikh i try what you type there is no error now thank you

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please accept the answer if you think it had helped and close this question.